# What is the result of this $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan x} {2+e^{x}} \ dx$ in terms of non-elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

I saw the integral in this question [Using Comparison test to determine if  $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\arctan x} {2+e^{x}} \ dx$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205812/using-comparison-test-to-determine-if-int-0-infty-frac-arctan-x-2ex) and saw that its value approximate is .408108504052, so I am interested in knowing what its result is in terms of non-elementary functions or a series expression

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What are your ideas?

Comment: @Accelerator I tried to solve using the arctangent series but got nowhere

Comment: You would have a better chance of receiving a really good and interesting answer if you show an honest and genuine attempt. That way, your post won't be closed.